# convert text file to JSON as key value pair or header with CSV in python or JavaScript or PHP

Tags: javascript, python, php, node.js

I have text file in this format.

https://drive.internxt.com/s/file/6c667ac1aa473f493252/c0918d6bc5217ea29f44fdf9182a6d284e2776a0efd2f51f61bb6a0a207afdca

I'd like to convert as CSV with header as in

[image]

or JSON key value pair.
Appreciate for guiding.

Comment: Please add the code where you tried to resolve this yourself. If you don't know how to begin, then you need more programming experience since this is a very simple function which can be solved in any language.

Answer (score 0):

learn `awk` and `sed` powerful tools just for this type of situation.

Comment: Thanks for advise. I prefer to use python , JS or PHP

Answer (score 0):

You should have posted the code that you tried.

Anyways, you can try `csv` lib from python to do that.

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows([line.split() for line in lines])
```